# CSSO npm not working while others are

Tags: node.js, npm, csso

I’m new to Node.js & npm and am trying to figure out why the uglifyjs module is working while the csso module is not.

i recently moved my global install to following location

```
/Users/myname/.node_modules_global/bin/npm
```

via this tutorial’s recommendation.

https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/

to show they are both installed globally i do this via the command line

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

and i get this result

```
/Users/myname/.node_modules_global/lib
    csso@3.1.1
    npm@5.3.0
    uglify-js@3.0.25
```

for testing purposes i navigate to a local static site and run the commands using the CLI.

the uglifyjs command works. but when running the command for csso which is

```
$csso style.css style.min.css
```

i get this error

```
bash: csso: command not found
```

i’m at a loss how to even troubleshoot except this.

Comment: Have you checked whether the PATH environment variable is properly set to include the new location?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing the CLI version. Please try:

```
npm i csso-cli
```

to install it.